# Converting fetch to ajax for use in stripe integration

Tags: javascript, php, fetch, stripe-payments

I have a problem with fetch on mobile google chrome. I want to try to convert it to ajax. I am using it for stripe implementation in php. This what I have done using fetch :

```
  var createCheckoutSession = function(planId) {
    var plan = {
          plan_id: planId
      };
  
      var data = new FormData();
 // we call the create my session page by providing a Plan ID which in turn will return a session object whose ID will be useful later on to redirect to checkout.
      data.append( "plan", JSON.stringify( plan ) );
    return fetch("/create-my-session", {
      method: "POST",
      body: data
    }).then(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      return result.json();
    });
  };
```

in create-my-session page I have this code:

```
$stripeService = new StripeService();
    $plan = json_decode($_POST["plan"]);
    $planId = $plan->plan_id;
    $session  = $stripeService->createCheckoutSession($planId);
    echo json_encode($session);
```

The above code is executed on click of this button :

```
   $('#subscribe').on('click',function(e){ 
        createCheckoutSession(MyChosenPlanID).then(function(data) {
          stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      //we redirect the user to a checkout page hosted by stripe that uses the session ID returned above
          sessionId: data.id
          }).then(handleResult);
        });
          });
```

what i have done so far in converting to ajax:

```
 var createCheckoutSession = function(planId) {
    var plan = {
          plan_id: planId
      };
  
      var datastream = new FormData();
      datastream.append( "plan", JSON.stringify( plan ) );

     $.ajax({

      type: "POST",
      url: "/create-my-session",
      data: {
        'info': datastream,
    },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
          
          var sessionobj = data;
          
      },
      error:function(response)
      {
          console.log("Data sending failed");
          console.log(response);
      }
  });
     
    
    return sessionobj ;
    }).then(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      return result.json();
    });
  };
```

and I kept everything else as it is.

Comment: Can you clarify the exact issue you're running into, does that code not do what you expect? I'm a bit confused by the goal overall, since `fetch` and jQuery's `$.ajax` do exactly the same thing as far as I know, they make an XMLHTTPRequest.

Comment: @karllekko thank you for your answer. the fetch is working fine. In fact I was trying to implement this in Drupal using php , my problem is that the link create-my-session checks if the user is logged in or not and acts upon this . for some reason if the user is logge din on the page where the subscribe button is located, it aappaesr as logged out on the create-my-session page if tested on Chrome for android. I tested it on desktop and on Iphone, it worked fine, so I suspect that the fetch is the reason if it is not compatible with android https://caniuse.com/fetch

Comment: Your link shows fetch works on Android. I don't think your issue with authentication has anything to do with using `fetch` versus using `ajax`, since they ultimately would just make the same request with the same cookies, so I'd debug further and look elsewhere.